# Scala: Use a Generic in Function Interface

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, object, generics

I want to implement a function (as an object), something like:

```scala
object Add extends ((Int, Int) => Int) {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
}
```

but I want to use Generics, because the Spark `Dataset` needs the Type like `Dataset[Int]`. *How can I write a function with it?* Because this one won't compile (unknown T):

```
object Something extends (Dataset[T] => Unit) {
 def apply(input Dataset[T]) = {
    ...
  }    
}
```

**Edit:**

Because the question appeared why I want to do this, in the end I want to write something like:

```
object Process {
  def doIt(config: Configuration) = {
    val step1 = Step1(config)
    val step2 = DoStep2(step1)
    Output(step2)
  }
}
```

It's only about how the source-code (should) look like. In a mathematical way you write a function like `f(x)`. With the possibility above I could write something like `Step1(x)` and it would look nearly similar to `f(x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object can not be generic.

But you can do something like this Instead.

```
object Something {
  def apply[T](ds: Dataset[T]) = {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This I did before and some people say that this `apply` is preserved for factoy-like-methods. Unfortunately.

Comment: @SleepyX667 Whoever said that is simple wrong. It is true that one great _(and common)_ use case for **objects** and their `apply` method is to serve as a factory or their companion **classes**. But that is all, you can also use objects to store helper methods, or to be part of an ADT or being their own entities or simple for whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
class Something[T] extends (Dataset[T] => Unit) ...
```

Comment: I want to use `Something` like:
`
val dataSet = DataSet[Int] 
Something[Int](dataSet)
`
is there a possibility to avoid the `new` for creating it?
It should look like a mathematical function in the source code.

Comment: @SleepyX667 Make `Something` a case class. `case class Something[T]() extends ...`

Comment: @SleepyX667 Or define `apply` method in companion object. `class Something[T] extends ...` `object Something { def apply[T]: Something[T] = new Something[T] }`

Comment: The downside of this, would be that for calling the function one would need to `Something(ds)()` or define apply on the class without parenthesis, to call it like `Something(ds).apply`.